# Excel is converting formulas to valued number

Tags: microsoft-excel

This has been happening to me and other people who are using Excel. A formula is entered in and for me after I press enter it will change the formula to the answer. Example, I will enter in `=A1/B2` and when I press enter, it will change what is in the cell and put `.5`. The formula is now gone.
For others, it seems the formula disappears after the worksheet has closed and when the worksheet is opened again, the formula is gone.
This is something new that has been happening for the past few months. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: If the formula bar [shows the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urmIS.png) but it [changes to the fixed value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwRAD.png) after you save/close/open the file, it may be that the file format is incompatible with formulas. For instance, you can add formulas into a CSV file but it is converted to a value when it is closed.

Comment: What you say might be the Case , but when saving , I think MS Excel will "warn" about that. @EngineerToast [[ I think , it is Possible that there is some VBA Macro executing in the Document , which might be converting that ]]

Comment: What kind of file format did you save? If you saved the Wordbook as .text or .csv file format the formula will return to the value directly without formulas.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the cell has been formatted to be "Hidden" and then the "Protect Sheet" command selected from the Review tab of the Ribbon menu system.

If done by first clearing the "Locked" formatting setting (so the cells are still editable after protection is set) and with the defaults that come up when in the Ribbon menu, such cells (ones formatted as "Hidden") can be selected and edited. Upon editing the correct result of the edit is displayed to the user, but the Formula Editor shows nothing.

Check by choosing the "Review" tab, then look in the "Protect" group (yes, "group"... the Ribbon menu is not a menu system with nested submenus, no, no, no...) for the first choice, "Protect Sheet"... if it says "**Un**protect Sheet" then click it and hope the jokester who set this up did not set a password before he quit the company and collected his last paycheck.